# Don't clean working directory after release:perform

Tags: maven-3, maven-release-plugin

Is there a way to have a completionGoal for mvn release:perform that won't clean the working directory of a project after successful deployment to a maven repo?

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Hm..are you creating the release from command line of from within a CI solution like Jenkins..cause release plugin doe not clean the working directory...or what exactly do you mean by `working directory`...may be you can give a little bit more details.

Comment: Both actually. When I run mvn release:perform, it removes release.properties and all files created when I run mvn release:prepare. Quoting [this](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html) "After the release is complete, the release.properties and other release files will be removed from the checkout."